# How to Click a Link in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Ima trying to click all the elements present in the Html

http://www.flipkart.com/ Under this Electronics -> Shop by Categories ->

below is the sample part of the Html

```
<a class="" data-tracking-id="0_Samsung" href="/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&amp;otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung">Samsung</a>

<a class="" data-tracking-id="0_All Brands" href="/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&amp;otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_All%20Brands">All Brands</a>


<a class="" data-tracking-id="0_All Brands" href="/laptops/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&amp;otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_All%20Brands">All Brands</a>
```

iam clicking using below

```
 WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.id("menu-electronics-tab-0-content"));
       List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
       System.out.println(""+lis.size());
       String[] linksText = new String[lis.size()];
       int index = 0;
       for(WebElement element : lis){

           linksText[index] = element.getText();

        String string = linksText[index];

        if(string.contains(" ")){
            linksText[index]= string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" ")); 
        }

           index++;
       }     
               for(index =0; index < linksText.length; index++){
           String xpath = "//*[contains(@href,'%s')]";
           String y = linksText[index];
                   String xpathOfElement = String.format(xpath, String.valueOf(y));
                      System.out.println("Name 1  "+driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)).getText());
                   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                          driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)).click();
```

When iam running the code it is proceeding till i = 12 till HP after that it is 
throwing an error. there are 83 Elements present. i need to click and navigate back

```
Name 1  Mobiles
Name 1  Bluetooth Headsets
Name 1  Laptops
Name 1  Apple
Name 1  
FAILED: Electronic
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 50.20 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'VALUED-8JGOG5PH', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 7d9304d9-fe1a-444d-b6b6-4669bfc46a33
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=26.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at Examples.FlipkartTest2.Electronic(FlipkartTest2.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'VALUED-8JGOG5PH', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous281959659031274025webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8179)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous281959659031274025webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10814)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous281959659031274025webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous281959659031274025webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:396)
```

is there any alternate method other than href to click the Link.

Comment: Have you tried finding the elements by their `XPath` value?

Comment: correct me if iam wrong xpath value will be same for certain elements like "All Brands"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an optional solution for you:**

1. Iterate all the links, and save the values of their `<href>` attributes in a list.
2. Iterate the list generated on the previous step, and navigate you browser to each URL.

Doing it this way will ensure that your code does not depend on the `WebElement` objects that you read from the DOM of the original web-page, and once you've collected all the URLs, you no longer need to remain on this web-page.

**Step #1:**

Before iterating `lis`, add `ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();`

**Step #2:**

Replace `driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)).click();`

With `urls.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)).getAttribute("href"));`

**Step #3:**

After iterating `lis`, navigate to each URL:

```
for (String url : urls)
    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com"+url);
```

Comment: Thanks but getting one error for the link org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@href,'Mixer/Juicer/Grinders')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 50.21 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html how to solve it ?

Comment: The `Mixer/Juicer/Grinders` string is in the element's text. In the element's href, it is a `mixer-juicer-grinders` string. So in `contains(@href,'Mixer/Juicer/Grinders')` - either change `href` to `innerHTML`, or change `Mixer/Juicer/Grinders` to `mixer-juicer-grinders`.